# Webpack error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | @charset "UTF-8";

Tags: javascript, css, utf-8, sass, webpack

I am trying to process a `.scss` file with Webpack 2.2.0 but instead of getting it injected into a `style` tag into my `index.html` file, I wanted to extract it into a `.css` file with ExtractTextPlugin.

The following is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
// webpack.config.js

let path = require('path');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
let extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                use: [

                    ///////////////////////////////////////
                    // THIS WONT WORK AND CAUSES THE ERROR
                    ///////////////////////////////////////

                    extractCSS.extract({
                        fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
                        loader: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                    }),

                    /////////////
                    // THIS WORKS
                    /////////////

                    // 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS
    ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug currently in ETP. I believe my switching use to "loader" that this will solve your problem. [Module parse failed error for SCSS file](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/342).